# Does console.log not work within socket.io event?

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io

Is there something that prevents a console.log() from firing within a socket.io event?  I am having a frustrating time with them.

```
socket.on('messageReceived', function(data) {
    console.log('Server ' + data.msg);
    var clientData = {'msg', 'Hello server'};
    socket.emit('clientResponse', clientData); 
});
```

in that code my node server receives the client response, but my browser console does not output the console.log. I don't get why... is this normal?

Comment: did your frontend receive clientData?

Comment: So, what you really mean is "why am I not getting the socket.io message"?

Comment: no that's not what I meant. I was just confused because I had two browsers open so I thought for sure I was receiving the message but only the console.log was not happening. I understand now that broadcast sends it out to everyone else...

Answer (score 1):

You can try `console.log('a')` in console of browser.

If you don't see a, I think you changed level log of console (`verbore`, `info`, `warn`, `error`) or used filter (you can change it in under of tab console).
I don't know what happen if `console` priint `a`.

Comment: I thought that also and checked the level first. I also tried outputting without the data and just a string... i don't get it

Comment: Do you test `console.log('a')` in console, and do you  see character 'a' ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I was using socket.broadcast.emit from the server instead of broadcast.emit.

I noticed when another browser I had open outputted the console.log.

Thanks everyone who read and put thought into this.

Comment: I don't have emit at all. But still console.logs under io.on() does not print

Answer (score 0):

I also had console.log not working and I have been spending the weekend debugging it. Nothing worked. (But my server was still running fine) Finally, I became fed up with it and I commented out my entire `io.on('connection')` code and it still ran.

Then, I went to my client and I saw that I still had my client sending and retrieving to and from my Heroku build that I set when I published the website.

So if you're having issues and nothing that you do is working, check the socket server that you're connecting to with your client.